# call local .asmx webservice from phonegap android app to get data?

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

i m creating one phonegap test application, for that i want data from database through webservice (.asmx). i m just newer for this technology. i have spent 2 days for this call posible bt couldnt.

```
    function test()
    {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
         $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
          $.ajax({
          data: "{}", 
             type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

             url: "http://localhost:xxxxx/yyyy/testservice.asmx?op=testfunction",
             success: function (msg) {
                $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.text); 
             },
             error: function (e) {
                 $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("unavailable");
             }
         });
    }
```

Its local service.

Comment: your webservice is local or live?

Comment: its local service in my system.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace `http://localhost:xxxxx/` with the actual internal IP address of the server (probably something like `http://192.168.x.x:xxxxx/`) - just make sure your server and mobile device are connected to the same network through wi-fi not gsm network. 
Also make sure you updated the domain white list. more info how to do that can be found here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

hope this will help, good luck!